# I need to color markers based on SQL databasefields using location[2] (status field)

Tags: google-maps

```
  <div id="map" style="width: 100%;
    height: 100%;"></div>


  <script type="text/javascript">
  //Populate locations from SQL database
        var locations = 
              [<ASP:Repeater id="MyRepeater" runat="server"><ItemTemplate>['<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "City") %>', ' <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StreetAddress") %>, <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "State") %>, <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Zipcode") %>','<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status") %>','<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CompanyName") %>','<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>' ],</ItemTemplate></ASP:Repeater>];


        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 10,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.4811689,-81.36875),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var marker, i;


    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        geocodeAddress(locations[i]);
        icon = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/" + location[2] + ".png"
    }

    function geocodeAddress(location) {
        setTimeout( function () {
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': location[1]}, function(results, status) {


    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {


    createMarker(results[0].geometry.location,location[0]+"<br>"+location[1]+"<br><div style=background-color:"+location[2]+";></div><br>"+location[3]+"<br><a target='_blank' href='editrequest.aspx?Id="+location[4]);


    }
    else
    {

    alert("some problem in geocode" + status);

    }
            }); }, i * 500);
}

    function createMarker(latlng,html){

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,


  }); 

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() { 
    infowindow.setContent(html);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() { 
    infowindow.close();
  });
}
  </script>
```

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow so forgive the formatting issues.

Comment: location[2] is this C# field '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status") %> in locations.  It is a color field with values of green, yellow etc.    I want to color the marker icons according to that field value.

Comment: Thanks for helping geocodezip what did I need to do to correct the formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `icon`-variable will be overwritten inside the loop. Pass the color as argument to createMarker instead:

```
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    createMarker(results[0].geometry.location,
                 'the infowindowhtml',
                  location[4]//as it seems the color is not location[2]
                 );

}
```

.......

```
function createMarker(latlng,html,color){

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    icon : "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/" + color + ".png"
  }); 

  //mouseover & mouseout.... 
}
```

Comment: It is properly passing the argument to the createMarker function it just has, for some reason, raised the OVER QUERY LIMIT flag.  If I increase the timeout it shows no markers.

Comment: I think I figured it out. My color fields use a capital ie. "Green" which when I hard code it in does not work.  I need to perhaps convert it to lowercase in my SQL statement or in .js.

Comment: It works!  I had to modify my SQL statement to convert "Status" to all lowercase using "LOWER(Status) AS StatusL" then change location[2] to <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StatusL") %> from <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status") %>.  I also had to increase the timeout for OVER QUERY LIMIT from 500 to 1500 and change "+ color +" to "+color+" in the createMarker function.  Dr.Molle you rock sir thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

It works! I had to modify my SQL statement to convert "Status" to all lowercase using `LOWER(Status) AS StatusL` then change `location[2]` to `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StatusL") %>` from `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status") %>`.

I also had to increase the timeout for OVER QUERY LIMIT from 500 to 1500 and change `+ color +` to `+color+` in the createMarker function.